# Problem downloading image from camera to Shotwell

Tags: downloads, camera, shotwell

The error message is: The camera is locked by another application

It occurs for both of my Canon cameras 7D and G12, so nothing to do with them.
It occurs since my upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

If I cancel the error message I do get to view the images to transfer (but not select them separately) and can download all but after closing and restarting Shotwell all bar the last few downloaded images have vanished!

I have seen the other post re this problem where unmounting it from the file browser was the solution - it's not here!

I would say the problem is with Ubuntu 20.04 and Shotwell but I'm at a loss to investigate it any further.

Comment: is this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190661/shotwell-cant-access-camera  helpfull?

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest and most robust way to import images from a digital camera is to buy a USB card reader ($10-$15) and put the SD card in it, then it behaves just like a USB drive, and you can use a normal file manager.

Yes, I know, low-tech and not technically challenging at all and *there must be a way to do this the regular way* etc., but that's what I've been doing for 17 years now, and it always served me well.

Those MTP protocols that cameras use when directly connected to the PC all have their weird aspects. I avoid them completely.

Comment: Yes thanks that's good advise! I'm going to do that from now on.

Comment: Then maybe consider marking the answer as the one that solved your problem. ;-)

Comment: A workaround isn't an answer to the problem.

Comment: Sure, you can fiddle around forever for principle's sake; it depends if you want a solution to the true problem (image import), or if you insist on getting something working that is broken by design (that MTP stuff). I am a very active amateur photographer since 2004, and I lost count in how many ways attaching a camera directly to a PC has been broken over the years.